# The "For Each" loop using IList (Of WebElements), stops while reading something #VB.net

Tags: vb.net, list, selenium-chromedriver

I created a Desktop application that relies on WhatsApp Chats.

when I try to Loops using "For Each" to read each buble chats.

The Loops suddenly breaks automatically when it find "deleted chat", "photos", or "voice recording".

Here my Codes

```
Dim Dari As String = Driver.FindElement(By.ClassName(CssClassName.WA_DIV_NAMA_PENGIRIM)).Text

'baca per pengirim'
CheckOrAddKirimanByNama(Dari)

'baca per bubble chat'
Dim Last As IList(Of IWebElement) = Driver.FindElements(By.ClassName(CssClassName.WA_DIV_TEXT_CHAT_MESSAGE_IN))

Dim ListPesan As New List(Of TextChat)

For Each z As IWebElement In Last
    Dim LastMsg = z.FindElement(By.CssSelector("div[Class='" & CssClassName.WA_SPAN_TEXT_CHAT & "']")).Text
    Dim Time = z.FindElement(By.CssSelector("div[Class='" & CssClassName.WA_SPAN_TEXT_TIME & "']")).Text

    Dim dtTime As DateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(Time).ToString("HH:mm")
    Dim startTime As DateTime = DTPStart.Value.ToString("HH:mm")
    Dim endTime As DateTime = DTPEnd.Value.ToString("HH:mm")

    If dtTime >= startTime AndAlso dtTime <= endTime Then
        ListPesan.Add(New TextChat(LastMsg, Time, 1, TextChat.STATUS_ACTIVE))
    End If
Next

tempKiriman.AddItem(Dari, ListPesan)
```

and this is my other class.

```
Public Class CssClassName
    Public Shared WA_DIV_BARCODE As String = "_1G1FQ"
    Public Shared WA_DIV_LIST_PENGIRIM As String = "_1MZWu"
    Public Shared WA_DIV_NAMA_PENGIRIM As String = "YEe1t"
    Public Shared WA_DIV_TEXT_CHAT_MESSAGE_IN = "message-in"
    Public Shared WA_DIV_PICTURE_CHAT_MESSAGE_IN = "j9c-4"

    Public Shared WA_DIV_BUTTON_DOWN As String = "_3DmTD"

    Public Shared WA_SPAN_NOTIFICATION_ACTIVE As String = "VOr2j"
    Public Shared WA_SPAN_NOTIFICATION_NON_ACTIVE As String = "_2gsiG"
    Public Shared WA_SPAN_TEXT_ON_LIST_PENGIRIM As String = "_3MjzD"

    Public Shared WA_SPAN_TEXT_CHAT As String = "_1wlJG"
    Public Shared WA_SPAN_TEXT_TIME As String = "_185ho"
    Public Shared WA_SPAN_TEXT_BOX_FOR_REPLY As String = "DuUXI"
End Class
```

please help me... thanks

Comment: We don't put solved in the title.  You accepted an answer, that's good enough.

Comment: Where is the For Each loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are my best guesses based on the information available, I hope one of them helps:

1. Driver.FindElements(By.ClassName(CssClassName.WA_DIV_TEXT_CHAT_MESSAGE_IN))

I can't see the definitions to be sure, nor the test samples or results, but I'm guessing that 'WA_DIV_TEXT_CHAT_MESSAGE_IN' is only returning pure text chat messages so none of the other ones you mentioned (which seems like *all* the others) are getting included?

2. ListPesan.Add(New TextChat(LastMsg, Time, 1, TextChat.STATUS_ACTIVE))
   Is "TextChat" the common base class for all of the message types you described?

And by association: Dim ListPesan As New List(Of TextChat)
Did you want to use an interface here instead of TextChat?

Anyway, sorry I cannot say for sure but it looks like those are the places where you might want to doubly make sure you're using the same shared parent/base class type.

Comment: Sorry before. I forgot to include the contents of CssClassName. I have added it now. The contents of CssClassName are only the names of the classes on WhatsApp Web.

Comment: yes, TextChat is Common Base for all message types.

where TextChat only contains String Of Message, Time Message, Count Message (if you find the same message more than 1), and Status of the message.

the task of the function that I made was to change the messages received from WhatsApp Web to the TextChat Class that I created.

Comment: When reading ordinary messages. there was no problem.

but after I debug. and I found where when the Function found "Deleted Messages", Photos, and Sound Recording. the function exits the Loop automatically. even though there are still unread message lists

Comment: I don't really understand how to use "IList" and "WebElements"

If I double-check, basically my basic logic and algorithms that I use should be fine.

Comment: I've found a solution to my problem.

Comment: I see you posted the answer below, I'm glad you figured it out, sorry I wasn't much help nor did I see your comments any sooner. I wanted to post as a comment on the main post but didn't have the rep. IList is basically just the list collection class only in its abstract interface form. As it is an interface it means anything that uses it in the creation of the implementing class must add in the List commands like 'add' 'remove' and 'clear'.

Comment: List of "IList" methods: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.ilist-1?view=net-5.0
List of "IWebElement" methods: https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/T_OpenQA_Selenium_IWebElement.htm

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution to my problem.

by changing the reading pattern in IWebElement

```
Dim LastMsg = z.Text.Substring(0, z.Text.Length - 5)
Dim Time = z.Text.Substring(z.Text.Length - 5)
```